# the following code is about rotating a sorted arrray by some value d

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop, rotation

my code is not working it is producing unexpected results.the code is about array rotation by using  a temp array . function "rotate" rotates the array , while function printArray prints the array .in the main function both functions are called. then there is cout with "hello". the overall output if "ellolloloohello". why am i getting this output.thanks

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;

 void rotate(int arr[],int d, int n){
int temp[d];
for(int i =0;i<d;i++){
    temp[i]=arr[i];

}
for(int i = 0;i<n-d;i++){
    arr[i] = arr[i+d];
}
for(int i =0 ;i < d;i++)
{
    temp[i]= arr[n-d+i];

}

}
void printArray(int arr[],int size){
for(int i =0;i<size;i++)
{

    cout<<arr[i]+" " ;
}
}
int main()
{

int arr[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
rotate(arr,3,10);
printArray(arr,10);
cout <<"hello";
}
;
```

the output is "ellolloloohello" instead of "hello". whats happening here?????

Comment: `cout<<arr[i]+" " ;`? You're adding a white space's ascii value to the int value of your array. Please make it `cout << arr[i] << ' ';`

Comment: `int temp[d];` this is against the standard. Please use std::vector

Comment: @theWiseBro `" "` is not the ascii value of a white space, but you seem to have spotted the problem.

Comment: @user253751 right. Thanks.

Comment: Problem here is that you code in `C` style when you use `C++`. Note there is ready algorithm for your problem [std::rotate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate).

Comment: Even if we disregard the fact that `int temp[d]` is not valid in C++ (some compilers support it, but it is a non-standard extension which is less reliable in several ways than using `std::vector`)  the last loop of `rotate()` does nothing except modify the array `temp`.  That array will cease to exist when the function returns, so the last loop does nothing at all that will be visible to the caller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters the variable length arrays

```
void rotate(int arr[],int d, int n){
    int temp[d];
    //...
```

is not a standard C++ feature. Either use an auxiliary standard container as for example std::vector or std::list or you should dynamically allocate an array.

In the last loop of the function

```
 void rotate(int arr[],int d, int n){
int temp[d];
for(int i =0;i<d;i++){
    temp[i]=arr[i];

}
for(int i = 0;i<n-d;i++){
    arr[i] = arr[i+d];
}
for(int i =0 ;i < d;i++)
{
    temp[i]= arr[n-d+i];

}
}
```

you are overwriting the array temp instead of the array arr.

And in the function printArray in this statement

```
cout<<arr[i]+" " ;
```

in the expression

```
arr[i]+" "
```

there is used the pointer arithmetic. That is the string literal `" "` is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element and the numeric value `arr[i]` is used as an offset for this pointer. Instead write

```
cout<<arr[i] << " " ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `cout<<arr[i]+" " ;` to `cout << arr[i] << ' ';`

And please use std::vector. `int arr[d]` is no c++ :(